# Java arrow from edge of screen to face object else where in map in game

Tags: java, algorithm, rotation, game-engine, angle

I have an arrow on the edge of the screen in my Java game that's supposed to point to an object else where on the map but it just keeps going round the screen and fails to point at the object, any ideas why?

Here's my code:

```
float angle = (float)Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(currentInteractive.getY()-player.pos[1], currentInteractive.getX()-player.pos[0]));
arrow.setRotation(angle);

float magnitude;
float abs_cos_angle = (float) Math.abs(Math.cos(angle));
float abs_sin_angle = (float) Math.abs(Math.sin(angle));
if (Main.DISPLAY_WIDTH/2*abs_sin_angle <= Main.DISPLAY_HEIGHT/2*abs_cos_angle)
{
    magnitude = Main.DISPLAY_WIDTH/2/abs_cos_angle;
}
else
{
    magnitude = Main.DISPLAY_HEIGHT/2/abs_sin_angle;
}
float ax = (float) (camera.viewPort.getCenterX() + Math.cos(angle)*magnitude);
float ay = (float) (camera.viewPort.getCenterY() + Math.sin(angle)*magnitude);

arrow.draw(ax, ay, Color.green);
```

Comment: generally speaking, it's not a good idea to just put a big chunk of code here. It's better to describe what you are doing in high level pseudo code, or at least give some conmments

Comment: Or put enough code that we can run it.  Is this Greenfoot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem, turns out it was because I hadn't converted the angle to radians and it was messing with the magnitude, I also had to encapsulate some parts of the maths with brackets to ensure it was calculated in the right order.

Here's my code now:

```
Interactive currentInteractive = interactiveList.get(i);

currentInteractive.draw();

float angle = (float)Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(currentInteractive.getY()-player.pos[1], currentInteractive.getX()-player.pos[0]));

arrow.setRotation(angle+90);

float magnitude;
float abs_cos_angle = (float) Math.abs(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)));
float abs_sin_angle = (float) Math.abs(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)));
if (Main.DISPLAY_WIDTH/2*abs_sin_angle <= Main.DISPLAY_HEIGHT/2*abs_cos_angle)
{
    magnitude = (Main.DISPLAY_WIDTH-20)/2/abs_cos_angle;
}
else
{
    magnitude = (Main.DISPLAY_HEIGHT-20)/2/abs_sin_angle;
}

float ax;
if(currentInteractive.pos[0] > player.pos[0]-(Main.DISPLAY_WIDTH/2) && currentInteractive.pos[0] < player.pos[0]+(Main.DISPLAY_WIDTH/2))
{
    ax = (float) currentInteractive.pos[0];
}
else
{
    ax = (float) (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)) * magnitude) + camera.viewPort.getCenterX()-10;
}

float ay;
if(currentInteractive.pos[1] > player.pos[1]-(Main.DISPLAY_HEIGHT/2) && currentInteractive.pos[1] < player.pos[1]+(Main.DISPLAY_HEIGHT/2))
{
    ay = (float) currentInteractive.pos[1];
}
else
{
    ay = (float) (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)) * magnitude) + camera.viewPort.getCenterY()-10;
}

arrow.draw(ax, ay, Color.green);
```